I'm trying to call a function from Flutter based on an event in the ios native, but flutterMethodChannel?.invokeMethod , not called
I'm trying to call a function from Flutter based on an event in the ios native, but flutterMethodChannel?.invokeMethod , not called
This is My AppDelegate class ..

import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging
import UserNotifications


@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    
    var flutterMethodChannel: FlutterMethodChannel?
    let channelName = "notification_channel"
    var notificationData : Any? = nil
    
    override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        }
        
        configureFlutterEngine()
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }
    
    
    
    override public func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any],
                                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        
        if application.applicationState == .active {
            showLocalNotification(with: userInfo)
        } else {
            Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
            showLocalNotification(with: userInfo)
        }
    }
    
    private func showLocalNotification(with userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
        if let data = userInfo as? [String: Any],
           let notificationID = data["id"] as? String,
           let title = data["title"] as? String,
           let body = data["body"] as? String
        {
            let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
            content.title =  title
            content.body = body
            content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
            content.userInfo = data
            notificationData = data
            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: notificationID, content: content, trigger: nil)
            
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { (error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error showing local notification: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    override public func  userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print("fcm_token Notification Clicked User Info = \(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)")
        flutterMethodChannel?.invokeMethod("onNotificationClick", arguments: notificationData){ (result) in
            if let resultString = result as? String {
                print(resultString)
            }
            completionHandler()
        }
        completionHandler()
    }
    
    override func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                         willPresent: UNNotification,
                                         withCompletionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions)->()) {
        withCompletionHandler([.alert, .sound, .badge])
    }
    
    private func getNotificationData(result: FlutterResult){
        result(notificationData)
    }
    
    @objc func configureFlutterEngine() {
        let flutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
        let flutterEngine = flutterViewController.engine!
        let binaryMessenger = flutterEngine.binaryMessenger
        
        let flutterMethodChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: channelName, binaryMessenger: binaryMessenger)
        flutterMethodChannel.setMethodCallHandler { (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) in
            print("fcm_token Method Call Handler")
            if call.method == "getNotificationData" {
                print("fcm_token getNotificationData")
                self.getNotificationData(result: result)
            } else {
                result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
            }
        }
    }
    
    override func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        print("fcm_token applicationDidBecomeActive")
        flutterMethodChannel?.invokeMethod("onNotificationClick", arguments: "ios string")
    }
    
}


And This is My Flutter Code 

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:logger/logger.dart';

class NativeNotificationConnector {
  static final NativeNotificationConnector instance =
      NativeNotificationConnector._init();
  NativeNotificationConnector._init();
  MethodChannel? _channel;

  void configureChannel() {
    _channel = const MethodChannel('notification_channel');
    _channel?.setMethodCallHandler(methodHandler);
  }

  Future getNotificationData() async {
    try {
      Logger().e('fcm_token getNotificationData');
      dynamic data = await _channel?.invokeMethod('getNotificationData');
      Logger().e('fcm_token notification data: $data');
      return await _channel?.invokeMethod('getNotificationData');
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      // Handle platform exceptions (e.g., method not found)
      Logger().e(e.message);
    }
  }

  // create a onNotificationClick method to receive the notification data from ios
  Future<void> methodHandler(MethodCall call) async {
    final String idea = call.arguments;
    Logger().e('fcm_token notification data: $idea');

    switch (call.method) {
      case 'onNotificationClick':
        onNotificationClick(idea);
        break;
      case 'selectNotification' :
        selectNotification(idea);
        break;
      default:
        Logger().e('fcm_token no method handler for method ${call.method}');
    }
  }

  // create onNotificationClick method to receive the notification data from ios
  void onNotificationClick(String data) {
    Logger().e('fcm_token notification data: $data');
  }

  void selectNotification(String data) {
    Logger().e('fcm_token notification data: $data');
  }
}

How To Solve This Problem ..
Note: I Need To Call Flutter Code From Native On User Tap Notification , I Dont Need To Use flutter_local_notification plugin ..
I Tried To Reverse the process (Call Native Code From Flutter) , This Worked Without Problems ..
